# Blueberry (Rabbiteye) help

Tags: pollination, blueberries

Can Pink Lemonade blueberry plants pollinate Powderblue blueberry plants and vice versa?

They are both Rabbiteye blueberry plants.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes:](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/blueberry-varieties-require-crosspollination-44002.html)

> Powder Blue: Pair with Brightwell, Pink Lemonade or Tifblue

> Pink Lemonade: Pair with Brightwell, Powder Blue or Tifblue

Their is a small catch:

The flowers should appear about the same time in your area or else it will not work.